# Is it customary to pay a share of property taxes in a Tenancy-in-Common (TIC) agreement according to the amount paid for your share?

Tags: real-estate, home-ownership, property-taxes

I'm looking at buying a Tenancy-in-Common (TIC) property in San Francisco for which the TIC agreement states the following about how property taxes are divided among co-tenants:

[image]

The thing is that prices have increased so much over the years that the tax-assessed value of the entire property is currently less than the listing price of just one interest in the property. So according to this formula, it seems like I would pay all the property taxes and other tenants would pay nothing, which seems unfair to me.

What I would find more reasonable is if the total property taxes over the assessed value of the property were subdivided amongst the co-tenants based on their percentage of ownership. Are there TIC agreements like this, or are almost all TIC agreements like the one above? Would it be feasible to negotiate a change in these terms?

Comment: I think you are reading this wrong. Unless you built the property from scratch (so the entire assessed value of the property is attributable to your improvements) or the other tenants paid $0 for their interest, there's no way you have to pay 100% of the property taxes.

Comment: I think you’re reading this with the assumption that the “ratio” mentioned is a number less than 1, even though you know it isn’t, and that leads to a nonsensical interpretation. Consider that the ratio for one cotenant may by 120% and the ratio for another cotenant may be 150%. Then the allocation of property tax is done according to those ratios.